# How to separate background HTTP requests

Tags: http, httpwebrequest, content-type

This is more of an issue of trying to understand how HTTP really works and then implementing it.

I need to have a HTTP analyzer that will be able to separate between the main page requests and "background" requests from some HTTP log data. The idea is to separate HTTP requests made by the user from those that happen automatically (loosely using this term) in the background. So, from the first few impressions of the HTTP data that I've seen it seems like when I go to any normal website an text/html object is fetched followed by a lot of other objects like css, xml, javascript, images etc.

Now, the problem is how do I separate these "background" requests where the user is actively not generating the requests. This will mostly be ad fetches, redirections and some Ajax based things from what I know.

Does anyone has any idea with regards to this. Some, experience or may be resources that you could point me to get started with doing this analysis?

Comment: I think the usual (and simplest) way is to separate them by filetype: `html`, `php`, etc. requests are the real hits, `css`, `js`, images files etc. are the "background" hits. Of course this does not account for Ajax requests, which may also hit `html` and `php` files.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to distinguish which requests were generated by the browser because of specific user actions or because of other automated processes from the bare HTTP requests. The browser/client it the only one that has such knowledge, so that you have to make it part of the picture, e.g. implementing the analyzer as a browser plugin or to embed an HTTP client as part of the analyzer itself.

If you're trying to create a generic tool to analyze traffic load, it's usually not meaningful to distinguish between traffic generated by user's direct "clicks" and automated requests.

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct and clean way to do this. However, you can get pretty close by filtering out requests for files that clearly are not "user" requests, like *.jpg. Furthermore, you can filter out what is not a HTTP/200 response (e.g., 301 and 302 redirects).

Try something along the lines of:

```
cat access.log
    | grep -E -v "(.gif|.ico|.png|.jpg|.jpeg|.js|.css) HTTP"
    | grep "HTTP/1.1\" 200"
```

(added line breaks for readability)